# Bootstrap - aligning columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I align two columns in the following way:

1. When they are both on the same line (when the screen size is wide enough to place them side by side) they should be aligned vertically. The shorter column should be on the center of the taller one.
2. When the screen shrinks so that they are placed one on top of another, they should be both centered horizontally.

I used the grid system with the image (img-responsive) on one column (`col-md-4`) and text(`h4`) on another(`col-md-8`). As the text is not as tall as the image when the screen is md or more the text should be displayed on the vertical center of the image right next to it. However after reaching screen sm or xs, I'd like it all to be displayed on the horizontal center of the container.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4"><img class="center-block img-responsive" src="foo.png" alt="foo" width="190" height="160" /></div>
   <div class="col-md-8">
      <h3>Foo image description</h3>
   </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for the suggestions

Here's the sample:
http://jsbin.com/lisetahupa/edit?html,output

Comment: You need to post a minimal, working example of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a Snippet. See [mcve] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You are using 2 col-md it was suposed to be used one for desktop and one for mobile well try this class `col-md-4 col-xs-2`